# Input Validation -Swift

Tags: swift, loops

I am trying to write a program where I ask the user to enter a number. If the user enters a number, the program would execute a print statement. This part I have covered but I'm having issues on how to ask the user for a new number if they did not enter one.

```
print("enter number")
if let input = readLine() {
    if let number = Int(input) {
        repeat {
            if number > 0   {
                print("haha")
            }
            else {
                print("not a positive number")
                print("enter another positive number")

            }
        } while number < 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current code also doesn't look like it works properly. What happens when i enter a negative number?

Comment: It works when you enter a negative number, but that's the part where I have issues.. how do I send the flow back to where the code asks for the number again?

Comment: That was my point.

Comment: lol.. that's mine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop needs to be at the top level with everything else inside. Break the loop when appropriate.

```
var more = true
repeat {
    print("enter number")
    if let input = readLine() {
        if let number = Int(input) {
            if number > 0   {
                print("haha")
                more = false
            }
            else {
                print("not a positive number")
            }
        } else {
            print("not a number")
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing entered")
        // maybe exit here too?
    }
} while more
```

Here I exit once a valid number is entered. Adjust how you wish to finish based on your actual needs.